# How to define a re pattern that matches parenthesis in pair or no parenthesis but not single parenthesis using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to define a re pattern that matches telephone number like

```
 (514) 123-4567
 514-123-4567
```

But it should not accept the single parenthesis like

```
(514 123-4567
514) 123-4567
```

I know I can fix it using stack, but how can I solve it in pure regular expression way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I thing this should to it: `(?:(?:\([0-9]*?\))|(?:[0-9]*))*`

Comment: You missed the spaces and `-`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, silly me, I forgot the or operator completely.

Comment: Should it match "12345678901234567890"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
^((?=.*\().*(?=.*\)).*|[^()]+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/3

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*(?<=\().*\).*)$|^[^\(\)]+$`

This one does not check phone numbers specifically, but applies your parenthesis rules to any string.

https://regex101.com/r/7RhcTq/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s1 = "(514) 123-4567"
s2 = "514-123-4567"
a = [s1, s2]
numbers = [re.findall("(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})", i) for i in a]
final_numbers = [[b for b in i if b][0][0] for i in numbers if i]
```