# re python either or but not requirements

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a re statement to say that a phone number format is acceptable.  If not, then ill raise a ValueError.

Acceptable:
(xxx) xxx-xxxx, 
(xxx)xxx-xxxx, 
xxx-xxx-xxxx

Not Acceptable:
xxx xxx-xxxx,
xxx xxx xxxx,
(xxx-xxx-xxxx

My expression works for the acceptable ones, but it still runs for the non-acceptable cases.  I'm not sure how to input the expression where having only space between the 3rd and 4th number are not acceptable.  And then making sure the area code has both parenthesis

```
r'\s*\(*(\d{3})\)*\s*\-*(\d{3})\-*(\d{4})\s*'
```

I'm also trying to create a tuple of 3 groups as well when inputting a phone number string.

```
phonenum=re.compile(r'\s*\(*(\d{3})\)*\s*\-*(\d{3})\-*(\d{4})\s*',re.VERBOSE).match('(123) 324244-123').groups()
print(phonenum)
```

Any hints on this?

Comment: i think what you want is lookahead (ie a space is only acceptable if it follows a `)`)

Comment: What makes the first one acceptable? What are the criteria?

Comment: Your regex contains `\(*` which means "zero or more open parens". That's not what you want.

Comment: The first is acceptable because the area code is surrounded in parenthesis. For \(*, I still want the option of either encompassing the area code with () or dont.  If I don't want the (), then the '-' would need to exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a re pattern that matches parenthesis in pair or no parenthesis but not single parenthesis using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347314/how-to-define-a-re-pattern-that-matches-parenthesis-in-pair-or-no-parenthesis-bu)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "(136) 923-2521"
data = re.findall("(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})|((?<!\()\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})", s)
if data and data[0][0] == s:
   pass #condition met
```

Further tests:

```
s =  ["(452) 342-2323", "(132)243-2423", "132-423-45242", "4523 432-2321", "232 452 2324", "(232-232-4221"]
for number in s:
    print (number, re.search("(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})|((?<!\()\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})", number).group(0) if re.search("(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})|((?<!\()\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})", number) is not None else None)
```

Output:

```
('(452) 342-2323', '(452) 342-2323')
('(132)243-2423', '(132)243-2423')
('132-423-45242', '132-423-4524')
('4523 432-2321', None)
('232 452 2324', None)
('(232-232-4221', None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using the | operator.  My main objective is to create a tuple of 3 elements to split out the 3 number section.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code:

```
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PREFIX_OPTION_1 = "prefix1"
    PREFIX_OPTION_2 = "prefix2"
    DIGITS3 = "digits3"
    DIGITS4 = "digits4"

    numbers = [
        "(123) 456-7890",
        "(123)  456-7890",
        "(123)456-7890",
        "123-456-7890",
        "123 456-7890",
        "123 456-7890",
        "(123 456-7890",
    ]
    pat_str = "^((\((?P<%s>\d{3})\) ?)|((?P<%s>\d{3})-))(?P<%s>\d{3})-(?P<%s>\d{4})$"\
              % (PREFIX_OPTION_1, PREFIX_OPTION_2, DIGITS3, DIGITS4)
    pat = re.compile(pat_str)
    for number in numbers:
        match = pat.match(number)
        if match:
            print("'{}' matches to: '{}', '{}', '{}'".format(
                number, match.group(PREFIX_OPTION_1) or match.group(PREFIX_OPTION_2),
                match.group(DIGITS3), match.group(DIGITS4)))
```

**Output**:

> ```
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46373507>c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe a.py
> '(123) 456-7890' matches to: '123', '456', '7890'
> '(123)456-7890' matches to: '123', '456', '7890'
> '123-456-7890' matches to: '123', '456', '7890'
> ```

***@EDIT0***:

- Adapted solution thanks to @Rawing and @GenXeral 's comments
- **Notes**:

  - When defining the pattern I, used old string formatting style since I didn't want to over complicate it by doubling braces as the new style requires for our case (check [[Python]: PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101))
  - It doesn't scale well (concerning prefix formats), every time a new prefix format should be added, the code (besides the pattern string itself) needs changes

Comment: You can replace `{,1}` with `?`. You can also shorten `(\(\d{3}\))|(\(\d{3}\) {,1})` to just `\((\d{3})\) ?`.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there a way to group this into 3 element tuple? I keep getting ('(123)', '(123)', None, None).

Comment: @Rawing: Thanks for the tips, too often I forget about `?` and go with the old way. Regarding the 2nd mention, I don't remember why the 1st part ended up in the answer since I removed it at some point (since it's contained by the 2nd one). @GenXeral: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the last part of the question :) . Anyway, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I won't focus on the python code, but related to the regex you can use a regex like this:

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\) ?|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

[image]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQggVf/1)**

The idea is to have an alternation to check how the string starts and have a common pattern for the ending part

Comment: Love the illustration and the idea on checking various alternations for the beginning requirements.  I'll try to incorporate this to my solution

Answer (score -3):

This is a duplicate, but here is a working solution: `(?:(?:\([0-9]*?\))|(?:[0-9]*)[- ])*`

Comment: when you say "this is a duplicate", what is it a duplicate of?

Comment: A question I answered yesterday.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a link so we can close this one as a duplicate. Also, this seems to match some of the "unacceptable" formats in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I would think Megalng is referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347314/how-to-define-a-re-pattern-that-matches-parenthesis-in-pair-or-no-parenthesis-bu/46347438#46347438)

Comment: Downvoted because neither this answer nor the referenced one works properly.